# Pass variables from Rails to coffeescript (javascript) dialog window for multiple images delete button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

So I have a bunch of images from a Rails loop in a div, each has a delete button below it. I need to pass the id of that image to a JQuery Modal Dialog box, but only for that particular image so that the link from the Dialog box sends the right image ID to the controller to delete it.

I read that I could convert ruby to javascript variables like this:

```
:javascript
    delete_image_path = "#{delete_image_path}"
    image_name = "#{image.name}"
    id = "#{image.id}"
```

Which is great, but of course the last image in the loop will always overwrite these variables and I don't get the ID for the proper image when trying to delete it.

Further investigation reveals that I can also use the data attribute and then read it with JQuery like this:

```
id: 'delete-link', data: { image_name: image.name, delete_dvd_path: delete_image_path, id: image.id }
# jquery
$('#delete-link').data('image_name')
```

My big problem is that all the links for the images have the same id, this is inside a Rails loop for all the images for a particular entry:

```
- @images.each do |image|
    = link_to 'Delete', '#', id: 'delete-link', :title => 'Delete this image', \
   data: { image_name: image.name, delete_dvd_path: delete_image_path, id: image.id }
```

I do, of course, realize that the issue is that my buttons all have the same ID and it's impossible to distinguish between them, what I don't kow is how to make them unique and then grab their ID in the coffesscript/javascript end of things.

I am, embarrasingly, at a loss as to how to send or get the right ID and image name for each image to the JQuery dialog box which then calls the Rails controller to delete the appropriate image with something like:

```
:coffee
  $(".delete-btn").click ->
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog
      titleClass: 'alert alert-danger'
      closeText: 'hide'
      title: 'Delete Image ' + image_name + '?'
      resizable: false
      height: 240
      width: 350
      modal: true
      buttons:
      ...
```

I'm pretty bad with javascript or JQuery but solutions are very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the links have the same id because in your params to link_to you have `id: 'delete-link'` which is causing all the links to have an id of 'delete-link'. You could make that unique by appending image.id to it.

Unless you're saying data-id is always the same?

Edit:
I can't tell from your code but I'm assuming `.delete-btn` refers to your delete links right? If so:

```
$(".delete-btn").click ->
    # this is in the scope of the .delete-btn event handler
    image_id = $(this).data('id')

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog
      titleClass: 'alert alert-danger'
      closeText: 'hide'
      title: 'Delete Image ' + image_name + image_id
      resizable: false
      height: 240
      width: 350
      modal: true
      buttons:
      ...
```

Comment: yes, of course i rewlize this, but how can i refer to the right id in jquery to get that particular image? that's the problem. how do i reference that id after the image name?

Comment: I see, you should be able to do: `$(this).data('id')` The `this` inside of an event handler is the DOM element that the event handler was attached to. Wrapping it with $() turns it into jquery object, which let's you call `.data()` on it.

Comment: You're saying to do this on the modal dialog box? Doesn't $this refer to the dialog box itself?

Comment: How stupid of me, I didn't realize I was in the scope of the button with the `$('delete-btn')`. Thanks a lot that did it. Now I need to figure out why my coffeescript isn't being called when the page hits the controller, but that's for another SO question ;)